# Preserve button width after making choice on bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, css

I have a bootstrap button and dropdown like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    CHOOSE OPTION
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I ensure the chosen option appears in the button text as follows:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().html($(this).html() + '<span class="caret"></span>');
 })
```

But when I choose an option the width of the button changes. How can I keep the width of the button the same after I make a choice?

Comment: why not set a width to the button?

Comment: Use css `#dropdownMenu1 { width: 300px;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can put a class in your css, which is loaded after the bootstrap css which sets the button width to a fixed width, such as:

```
.toggleClass .btn {
width: 300px;
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
}
```

But you should really ask yourself if that's really what you want to do.  Because you'll have to set the width to be wide enough for the longest option in the dropdown and that might not be aesthetically pleasing for shorter options. Also, if you set the width of the button, then it won't be responsive for smaller screens and devices unless you create media queries in your css to handle for smaller screens and this will be hard to manage. You'd be creating more work for yourself, but if for some reason it's necessary, like the client demands it, then the above is one way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

@bdubay was the closest. What worked was:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
    width: 160px !important;
    min-width: 160px !important;
    max-width: 160px !important;
}
```